# navigator.share() is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `navigator.canShare()` and `navigator.share()` to experiment with websharing in a react app.

When I call `navigator.canShare()` in react, I get the following run time error:

```
TypeError: navigator.share is not a function
```

How can I get react to recognize `navigator.canShare()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share), you can only use `navigator.share()` over HTTPS

> Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

Comment: thanks I missed that.  my local dev is running on http.

Comment: even on this page with https though if you open up the devtools `navigator.share` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Like other answers said, you can only use `navigator.share()` over HTTPS.

What you can do is checking

1. If the navigator object has a share property
2. Check if `navigator.canShare()` is `true`

```
if (navigator.share && navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
   navigator.share(shareData)
} else {
   // Do something else like copying the data to the clipboard
}
```

PS: an easy way to test your local host using https (so you can see if this code works) is using some tools like mkcert

Answer (score 1):

MDN also says:

"Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and http://.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely.
Note: Firefox 84 and later support http://localhost and http://.localhost URLs as trustworthy origins (earlier versions did not, because localhost was not guaranteed to map to a local/loopback address)."

Not sure if this means HTTPS is not required locally or not, but I'm getting the same error, even with the Permissions-Policy header.